# Bash script stops execution in the middle of the script without any error

Tags: bash, scripting

I have this simple bash script that gets a copy from my dev server:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M.%S`
BASEDIR="/var/www/db"
RELEASEDIR="$DATE";
RELEASEDIRFULL="$BASEDIR/releases/$RELEASEDIR"
mkdir -p "$RELEASEDIRFULL"
echo "Chdir to \"$RELEASEDIRFULL\""
cd "$RELEASEDIRFULL"
echo "Getting copy from dev"
ssh dev.example.tld "cd /tmp; cd /sites/db; tar -zcvp --exclude data --exclude scripts -f - *" | tar zxvpf -
ln -s /var/www/db/data data
ln -s /var/www/db/scripts scripts
cd $BASEDIR
rm htdocs; ln -s releases/$RELEASEDIR htdocs
```

Recently it stopped working properly with no apparent reason. It gets to the ssh line, executes it fine (files appear on live server) but does not proceed with ln commands. If I comment the ssh line out, ln lines will get executed properly.

UPDATE: I noticed that when I'm logged on as www-data and start the script, it completes as expected, without errors.

Comment: "If I comment the ssh line out," ...?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's easier to format code by indenting it with four spaces; that way, it doesn't insert arbitrary line breaks that seem to confuse people.

Comment: The two `cd` commands in the `cd /tmp; cd /sites/db;` part of the `ssh` command are redundant (you only need the second) but harmless - not the source of your problem.

Comment: Yes, I noticed them too. But as you, I'm not considering them harmful.

Comment: Is it possible the ssh command is returning non-zero and you have errexit enabled?

Answer (score 1):

No time to check up the man page, but looks like your tar input is `- *` - all files + stdin? Are you meaning `--` for suspension of further argument processing (if tar supports that)

Comment: If it is indeed waiting for stdin, it should continue running after a Ctrl+D.

Comment: Kev, the input is "*" (all files) and the "-" is an argument for the option preceeding it: the "-f" or output file. The "-" means stdout here.

Comment: I also tried to relocate the -f - option but that did not help.

Comment: Henno, you're right on the '-' - I'm no great tar expert. Always, just noticed that you said it had been working but had stopped. Have you got some unusual timing issue going on caused by a remote directory that's increasing in size? Can you get the remote command to work with a single file, or not tarring it at all? I'll stress that I'm speculating here and throwing ideas in. Also, could you use scp directly for the copy with its built-in compression?

Comment: @Kev, I noticed that executing the script under www-data works. I updated the question with this new information.